# WSL2 Ubuntu Terminal not updating stdout

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows

I run Ubuntu on WSL2 in Win10. The problem I have is that there is no live output to stdout in the WSL terminal (nor Windows Terminal) unless I press a key, like down arrow or space. Here I pressed it several times, notice the time elapsed:

[image: WSL Terminal Window]

I haven't touched the keyboard for a while and no update to stdout, started pressing space:

[image: WSL Terminal missing output]

I have disabled QuickEdit mode and other stuff but I still have the same problem, is there any solution to it?

[image: WSL Terminal Properties]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Not everybody is able to see images, or see them well. Search engines can't do much with images. I can't copy your commands and try them out locally. Instead of pasting screenshots, copy text from the WSL window and paste it into Stackexchange.

Comment: I have this issue randomly.  The Ubuntu terminals normally do the right thing but occasionally I will have to press a key to get it to update